# Pointer arithmetic with multidimensional Array Notation

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

This is my first question :)

```
double MyArray[][6];
double* Myptr = MyArray[0];
```

So i've been wondering why, in pointer Arithmetic, I can notate a pointer to move in a single dimension like this,

```
*(Myptr + i);
```

but if i try to move through the dimensions  of the array using a for loop it won't let me

```
*(*(Myptr + i) + j);
```

However it does let me use this notation with the array itself.

```
*(*(MyArray + i) + j);
```

I wanted to know why is this a restriction? or maybe i am writing it down incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Myptr` is a pointer to double, so `*(Myptr + i)` is a double, and while you can add `j` to that, you cannot dereference the result.

Had you declared `Myptr` like this:

```
double (*Myptr)[6] = MyArray;
```

then `Myptr` would be a pointer to an array of 6 `double`s. Consequently `*(Myptr + i)` would be a `double[6]`, and the expression would work.

That you can index arrays using this syntax is unfortunately surprising to people who see it the first time and have never been taught about pointer decay. A funny thing about arrays in C and C++ is that they decay into pointers in almost all circumstances. What this means is that very nearly always when you use an array (exceptions exist), the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and the rest is done with pointer arithmetic.

For example, this is the case when you write `MyArray[i]`. The standard defines `MyArray[i]` to mean `*(MyArray + i)` (the standard uses more parentheses, but this is what it boils down to), which makes sense when you understand that `MyArray` decays to a pointer, `i` is added to this pointer, and the resulting pointer is dereferenced. It also explains why `i[MyArray]` is equally valid (if in bad style).

In the context of multidimensional arrays, it is important to understand that a multidimensional array is merely an array of arrays. `MyArray` is, in your case, an array of arrays of doubles. `MyArray[0]` is, then, an array of doubles. In pointer decay, `MyArray` decays to a pointer to array of doubles, and when you dereference that pointer and work with the array it points to, then *that* array also decays to a pointer (to double) when you work with it. It's decay all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, MyPtr is only one dimensional, because it was assigned to a specific "array" in MyArray.

Comment: oh.. I see, so the pointer will in fact be able to move throught the 2-D array, but just as 1-D.

Meaning that *(Myptr + i); were i can cover the entire multiarray?

Comment: Nevermind I didn't take into consideration that MyPtr is a double pointer.  See other answers.  But most likely yes to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

MyArray has type `double[][6]` and MyPointer has type `double*`.

Now arrays and pointers are different, but this is not important in this context. Both variables have array/pointer thingies in their types, but My Array has two (count them: `[]` and `[6]`) and MyPointer has only one (count it: `*`). Which is why you can apply dereferencing (that's the `*` operator) to MyArray twice, and to MyPointer only once.

Now if you want to have a pointer that can be used in much the same way you use MyArray, this is possible, but its type will not be `double**` (because arrays and pointers *are* different). You write it this way:

```
double (*MyPointer2)[6] = MyArray;
```

This one has two array/pointer thingies in its type so you can apply dereferencing twice to it.

Answer (score -1):

Because `Myptr` is a `double*`. A pointer to a double. It has no knowledge of the array dimensions.

Comment: Can you make a suggestion, how can I make my pointer have knowledge othe dimensions?